# I want to join two inputs in one var at html on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms, input

I'm using wordpress but making my own form for payments, i have **two inputs of type select, like this:**

```
<div id="S03" class="Selectos"><select tabindex="4" name="Mes" required="">
<option...[Code goes on]
```

**And this:**

```
<div id="S04" class="Selectos"><select tabindex="5" name="Ano" required="">
<option...[Code goes on]
```

Those works fine, but i want to join them in one input, i have research all day long, i found some clues about what i have to do, but in especifics no one does help me.
**This is the input for the joining:**

```
<input id="Expires" name="Expires" type="hidden" />
```

**And the way i call the form:**

```
<div class="container"><form id="contact" class="RV_donateForm" action="https://eps.banorte.com/secure3d/Solucion3DSecure.htm" method="post">
```

**And how it close:**

```
<fieldset><button id="contact-submit" name="submit" type="submit" data-submit=" ">Donar</button></fieldset>
</form></div>
```

Then i look for some way to joining and this one looks the better way to do it **at the submit event:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
button.onclick = function (){
document.getElementById('Expires').value = document.getElementById('S03').value + '/' + document.getElementById('S04').value; cn = document.getElementById('Expires').value ; 
alert(cn);
 };
</script>
```

Well, at the bank 'post' they throw me all the vars ok, except for Expires that never joins and shows null, and i notice also because it never show me the alert. I'm new at html and JavaScript, and i'm not sure what could be wrong. All the code on the file are on this order for exception that the call of the form is at the beginning of everything, ¿maybe is the position on line that i have to put the javascript?
I appreciate any help. Thanks a lot stackfellas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! It does work like Omar says, but loading the addEventListener at onload body function, it will run the function that the event refers when you click on submit button.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function putExpires(){
var cm = document.getElementById('S03').value;
var ca = document.getElementById('S04').value;
document.getElementById("Expires").value = cm + '/' + ca;
var cn = document.getElementById("Expires").value;
}
function load() { 
  var button = document.getElementById("contact-submit");
  button.addEventListener("click", function(){putExpires()}, false); 
} 
</script>
<body onload="load();">
```

Thanks Omar!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

I guess you first need to get the button, then add the listener

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var button = document.getElementById('contact-submit')
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('Expires').value = document.getElementById('S03').value + '/' + document.getElementById('S04').value; 
  cn = document.getElementById('Expires').value ; 
  alert(cn);
});
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, look at the form if you want https://rompeviento.tv/?page_id=41450 Pass: 159
I'm checking on what you share me anyway